# python get method not exporting all data in csv file

Tags: python, mongodb, csv

I created the python script for exporting csv from Mongodb. it did not work very well because it did not export all data in the fields from mongodb. I use get method because some records are missed in collections.

mongodb sample:

```
"experience": [
        {
            "order": null,
            "date": {
                "to": ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:31.872Z"),
                "from": ISODate("2003-08-16T21:24:31.872Z")
            },
            "description": "Trained horses for various competitions. ",
            "company": "D2 Ranch",
            "position": "Horse Trainer"
        },
        {
            "order": null,
            "date": {
                "to": ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:31.872Z"),
                "from": ISODate("2003-08-16T21:24:31.872Z")
            },
            "description": "Trained horses for various competitions. 2",
            "company": "D2 Ranch 2",
            "position": "Horse Trainer 2"
        }
    ]
```

the python script:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import codecs
import csv
cursor = db.user_profiles.find ({}, {'_id':1, 'experience.description':1, 'experience.position':1})
with codecs.open('skills.csv','w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    fields = ['_id', 'experience.description',  'experience.position']        
    write = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fields)
    write.writeheader()
    for x in cursor:
    x_id = x['_id']
        for y in x.get('experience', {}):            
            z = {
            '_id':x_id,                        
            'experience.description':y.get('description',None),
                'experience.position':y.get('position',None)}            
        write.writerow(z)
```

the problem is it skips the second record( position: "Horse Trainer 2" )in experience field. Appreciate for any helps, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mongo query is good, at least with version 3.4.4. It returns list of dicts like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59995fb7513601164f1325f8"),
    "experience" : [
        {
            "description" : "Trained horses for various competitions. ",
            "position" : "Horse Trainer"
        },
        {
            "description" : "Trained horses for various competitions. 2",
            "position" : "Horse Trainer 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems that problem lies in your's python script (or its formatting, what matters in python). Right now on each experiences list this code stores **only one** element. Row writing code is run only after for loop. It should be inside, as follows:

```py
for y in x.get('experience', {}):            
    write.writerow({
        '_id':x_id,                        
        'experience.description':y.get('description',None),
        'experience.position':y.get('position',None)
    })
```